# SOAP XML envelope

Tags: xml, soap, wsdl

In sample soap XML request message, I noticed that there are soap envelope tag as

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<Header>
...
```

Is it okay to remove these tags? For example,change the soap message as,

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
<Header>
...
```

Is this standard that all soap message must have?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The soap message is required, the namespace may be used by the receiving end to determine the version of the soap message. The namespace you are using, from what I understand, says this message follows `Soap 1.1` standards. If you try to use `Soap 1.2` features in that message, the server will most likely get confused.

**Section 4.1.2 of the soap 1.1 standard**

> SOAP does not define a traditional versioning model based on major and
>   minor version numbers. A SOAP message MUST have an Envelope element
>   associated with the "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
>   namespace. If a message is received by a SOAP application in which the
>   SOAP Envelope element is associated with a different namespace, the
>   application MUST treat this as a version error and discard the
>   message. If the message is received through a request/response
>   protocol such as HTTP, the application MUST respond with a SOAP
>   VersionMismatch faultcode message (see section 4.4) using the SOAP
>   "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" namespace.

[soap envelope in 1.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/NOTE-SOAP-20000508/#_Toc478383494)
[soap envelope in 1.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/soap12-part1/#soapenv)